# Refactoring the signature tags

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request, tag-synonym-process, tag-disambiguation

I'm doing the rounds around [signature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/signature) again and I find as usual that only one in twenty questions tagged signature is actually on topic. The signature tag has been defined to mean method signatures. However - as you may guess - most questions should be tagged [digital-signature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/digital-signature) instead. A good second are questions about email signatures, followed by (not there yet) written signatures, for instance as images included in PDF-documents. Oh yeah, and there are some actual questions about method, class or API signatures as well.

Would it be a good idea to work towards the following situation?

1. merging [signature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/signature) into [method-signature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/method-signature);
2. making [function-signature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/function-signature) as a synonym of [method-signature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/method-signature);
3. making [signature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/signature) a synonym for digital-signature;
4. introducing a new tag [email-signature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/email-signature);
5. introducing a new tag [written-signature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/written-signature).

**Edit:**
Blacklisting the signature tag instead of making it a synonym for digital-signature (in item 3) seems an even better choice as it would require posters to choose a correct tag, see the comments.

Because I'm having to perform an awful lot of tag edits as it is currently going. It's also impossible to follow any of the above tags without seeing all the digital-signature related questions.

If we decide to go for the above situation how should we proceed?

Comment: Note that I just did the rounds again, so there may have been quite a few tag-edits for the previous and current month.

Comment: IMHO `signature` is far to ambiguous. Best would be to blacklist it and use `*-signature`.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker I could certainly live with that, it would make posters to have a second look at the tag they actually want for their question. Good one. I didn't even consider blacklisting the tag. I'll amend the question.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker Could you maybe post it as an answer? Would the merge in list item 1 still make sense?

Comment: If you don't let a tag just be a contextual tag, similar to [debugging], [performance], [exception], etc, then you'll have a cruddy job that's never done.

Comment: @HansPassant Those terms do mean approximately the same even if in different contexts. These signature meanings are more distinct in the context of programming in my opinion. I guess your answer would be to make the signature tag to be generic? Because currently it certainly isn't.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker Should I just create a new question (linking to this one) asking for a black listing of signature? I presume that we then can leave the current signature tagged questions alone and point to the more specific signature tags using the signature excerpt? I'm not sure how blacklisting works.

Comment: Hmm, it looks like I first should try and burninate the tag to see if it comes back. I'm pretty sure that it will though.

Comment: For now I've created new descriptions for signture and method-signature, see if it helps/

Comment: The problem remains there. I've come this far with exactly the same question. 7 of the last 50 questions would be on-topic. The new description does not help much because the short text ends in _"The signature tag should ..."_ and you have to click to see all. +1 blacklisting

Answer (score 8):

The tag excerpt as it is, lacks usage guidance.

> Signature represents the parameter profile of a subprogram (function or procedure). It consists of number, type and order of its parameters.

If you don't blacklist it, at least change it so that is not only a definition, but also points to the tag of the most mis-selected uses.

Not many people read the excerpts (in my experience), but if they do read this one they are not being helped much to decide that the might need the digital-signature tag and to go there if this was the wrong tag to select.

Comment: I largely agree with this, we should at least change the description. But as you say, most people don't read excerpts (let alone experts, check the first sentence of your post :) ). Do you agree that blacklisting it would be the preferred option?

Comment: @MaartenBodewes I have been dealing more with digital signatures, so I think I might make this mistake as well having read the excerpt I understand that that kind of signatures could use the name as well. Blacklisting is more fair to the users of the site unless there is a few orders of magnitude more people using signatures for one use or the other.